# Contacts and contact_groups in nagios configuration

Tags: notifications, nagios

Can I have in nagios host and service config, specified contacts and contacts_groups together? I mean if I'll not notify only contact or only group.

e.g.

```
define host{
    host_name           bogus-router
    alias               Bogus Router #1
    address             192.168.1.254
    parents             server-backbone
    check_command           check-host-alive
    check_interval          5
    retry_interval          1
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_period            24x7
    process_perf_data       0
    retain_nonstatus_information    0
    contacts                specyfic-admin
    contact_groups          router-admins
    notification_interval       30
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options        d,u,r
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

From the [documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#host):

> **contacts**: This is a list of the short names of the contacts that
> should be notified whenever there are problems (or recoveries) with
> this host. Multiple contacts should be separated by commas. Useful if
> you want notifications to go to just a few people and don't want to
> configure contact groups. You must specify at least one contact or
> contact group in each host definition.
>
> **contact_groups**:   This is a list
> of the short names of the contact groups that should be notified
> whenever there are problems (or recoveries) with this host. Multiple
> contact groups should be separated by commas. You must specify at
> least one contact or contact group in each host definition.

Actually - now that I copy that I'm not so sure it describes the answer properly.

You may also want to look at [Object Inheritance](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectinheritance.html).

But, the short answer is still a ***yes***.